# Regex that match multiple format to extract aws accountid

Tags: regex, go

I want to use one regex to extract the aws account id for two types of format

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:1234567890:instance/i-0a89fdbedc3f1d76a
arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
```

I.e., the regex should be able to match `1234567890` in both lines.

I know how to create regex for each format, but want to have one single regex if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following regexp: `arn:aws:(?:ec2|iam):[^:]*:([0-9]+):`
The prefix is `arn:aws:`, followed by either `ec2` or `iam` and one may-be-empty segment. After the prefix there must be a non-empty group of digits. It is exactly the group with the instance number.

Example https://go.dev/play/p/mP6VyIYa3v_N

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const (
    s1 = "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:1234567890:instance/i-0a89fdbedc3f1d76a"
    s2 = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
)

func main() {
    reStr := `arn:aws:(?:ec2|iam):[^:]*:([0-9]+):`
    re, err := regexp.Compile(reStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    m1 := re.FindStringSubmatch(s1)
    fmt.Println("User id in ec2: ", m1[1])
    m2 := re.FindStringSubmatch(s2)
    fmt.Println("User id in iam: ", m2[1])
}
```

This regexp uses non-capturing group `(?:ec2|iam)`. The submatch that corresponds to this group is not included in the array returned by `regexp.FindStringSubmatch`. This is done for conveniece only: the array returned by `FindStringSubmatch` has only 2 elements - the full match and the match for the group `([0-9]+)`.

You can use full group `(ec2|iam)`. In this case the User ID group will have index `2` in the array of matches returned by `FindStringSubmatch`.

Comment: Could you explain the regex, such as (?:)

Comment: @drdot added explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Dont need RegExp, just pick out the fifth column:

```
package aws

import (
   "strconv"
   "strings"
)

func extract(s string) (int, error) {
   split := strings.SplitN(s, ":", 6)
   return strconv.Atoi(split[4])
}
```

https://godocs.io/strings#SplitN